# variable function not being change using a second function value

Tags: excel, vba

Was trying to rotate the PiqA values from

D to N, N to F1, F1 to F2 and F2 back to D.

The idea is to make a work calendar where each day will be D, N, F1 or F2 but for some reason the variables in function `PiqSt` are not being changed;

```
Public PiqA As String
Public PiqB As String
Public PiqC As String
Public PiqD As String

Sub Calendario()
Cells.Clear

Columns("A:AJ").ColumnWidth = 3.5
Columns("A:AJ").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
Cabecalho

End Sub

Sub Cabecalho()
Dim MyYear As Variant
Dim MyMonth As Variant

'MyYear = InputBox("What year ?")
'MyMonth = InputBox("What month ?")
MyYear = "2015"
MyMonth = "2"
TDaysMonth = Day(DateSerial(MyYear, MyMonth + 1, 1) - 1)

Range("A1:AF1").Merge
Range("A1").Value = Format("1/" & MyMonth & "/" & MyYear, "mmmm")
Range("A3").Value = "A"
Range("A4").Value = "B"
Range("A5").Value = "C"
Range("A6").Value = "D"

PiqA = "D"
PiqB = "F1"
PiqC = "N"
PiqD = "F2"

For I = 1 To TDaysMonth
    Cells(2, I + 1).Value = I
    Cells(7, I + 1).Value = Left(Format(I & "/" & MyMonth & "/" & MyYear, "dddd"), 1)

    Cells(3, I + 1).Value = PiqA
    PiqSt ("A")
    'Cells(4, I + 1).Value = PiqB
    'Cells(5, I + 1).Value = PiqC
    'Cells(6, I + 1).Value = PiqD
Next I

End Sub

Function PiqSt(Piq)
If Piq = "A" Then
    PiqA = NextSt(PiqA)
ElseIf Piq = "B" Then
    PiqB = NextSt(PiqB)
ElseIf Piq = "C" Then
    PiqC = NextSt(PiqC)
ElseIf Piq = "D" Then
    PiqD = NextSt(PiqD)
End If
End Function

Function NextSt(Status)
If Status = "D" Then
    Status = "N"
ElseIf Status = "N" Then
    Status = "F1"
ElseIf Status = "F1" Then
    Status = "F2"
ElseIf Status = "F2" Then
    Status = "D"
End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you aren't passing anything back from the function.  Specifically `NextSt`

Try using `Select Case` instead of a bunch of `IF` statements.

Also `PiqSt` doesn't need to be a function at all.  I'm going to include the code that needs changed.

```
Sub PiqSt(Piq As String)

    Select Case Piq
        Case Is = "A"
            PiqA = NextSt(PiqA)
        Case Is = "B"
            PiqB = NextSt(PiqB)
        Case Is = "C"
            PiqC = NextSt(PiqC)
        Case Is = "D"
            PiqD = NextSt(PiqD)
    End Select

End Sub
```

This Function had `Status` being set, but you never set `NextSt = Status`.  The Function passes a value back in its own name.  So you'd say `someVariable = NextSt(string)`

```
Function NextSt(Status As String) As String

    Select Case Status
        Case Is = "D"
            Status = "N"
        Case Is = "N"
            Status = "F1"
        Case Is = "F1"
            Status = "F2"
        Case Is = "F2"
            Status = "D"
    End Select

    NextSt = Status

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks allot mate... I am kind new to this language and did not remember the Select Case. And yehh you did well changing as well the function to a sub rotine because in beguining i have that has a function because i was calling it directly in the cell part but them i change because it was not making many sense to me...

Comment: Glad to help.  The main part though I'm pretty sure is that `NextSt = Status` needed set.

Comment: Yehh when i was checking the code i was asking my self that... Does all functions will have the hability to have a variable set with there name ? I mean, the function result can be always set like it was a variable ?

Comment: Yes, typically, you should declare what TYPE of result gets passed back. `Function funcName(arg1 As Type) As VariableType` The function works just like a function in the worksheet.  You put arguments into it, and it RETURNS something back.  A `Sub` will perform operations and do things for you, but not return a value.  It can SET variables to values, or set worksheets values, but not pass a result back through calling it.  In essence, the Function becomes a variable in a way.